# Understanding a C function for C# translation

Tags: c#, c, code-translation

I am side-checking some code that was translated from C to C#. I have a question on the original C:

```
...
#define getblock(p, i) (p[i])
...
void MurmurHash3_x86_32 ( const void * key, int len,
                          uint32_t seed, void * out )
{
  const uint8_t * data = (const uint8_t*)key;
  const int nblocks = len / 4;
  int i;

  uint32_t h1 = seed;

  uint32_t c1 = 0xcc9e2d51;
  uint32_t c2 = 0x1b873593;

  const uint32_t * blocks = (const uint32_t *)(data + nblocks*4);

  for(i = -nblocks; i; i++)
  {
    uint32_t k1 = getblock(blocks,i);
...
```

The part `for(i = -nblocks; i; i++) ...` is this looping through the data backwards? I've never seen data referred to with a negative index.

Comment: Why not debug it or just print out `i` at the start of each loop to see what happens?  That should make the behavior pretty clear.

Comment: I am writing in C# under Visual Studio. I believe the source is GNU C.

Comment: So you have no means at all of executing the original code?  If you're doing a rewrite I'd find a way of fixing that; you should be able to run snippets of the code that you're translating to help you better understand what it's doing.  Not being able to execute any C code at all is worse still, and shouldn't be too hard to remedy.

Comment: You're right. I was just wondering if there was a simple explanation of this function.

Comment: There is, but my point is you should be able to figure this out on your own by executing it, even if you don't understand what it does just by reading it, or at the very least you should be able to confirm your guess as to what it does by running it.  If you can't do that here it'll just make the less complex aspects of the translation that much harder to solve.

Comment: I agree, but actually this is the only part that was unclear.

Comment: It uses negative values because the *blocks* pointer points to the end of the object.  This is otherwise a *very* dangerous algorithm and quite unsuitable for managed code.  It assumes that all of the bytes in the object are part of fields of the object.  That isn't true in native code and not true (and undiscoverable) in managed code.  It is only useful for simple native types, the .NET ones already have a very good hash algorithm.

Comment: @HansPassant I will simply loop forwards in .Net, which is correct for the platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not looping through the data backwards. It starts at the beginning of data, and indexes up.

As you can see, here the pointer "blocks" is advanced past "data" already. It points "nblocks" past the beginning of data.

```
const uint32_t * blocks = (const uint32_t *)(data + nblocks*4);
```

So, you need a negative index to get to the beginning of data (-nblocks). The start of data is precisely at "blocks[-nblocks]". The "for" loop simply starts there, and counts up.

```
for(i = -nblocks; i; i++)
```

Comment: But why would you do that? What do you gain by explicitly pointing at the end of your data and then using negative indexes to traverse?

Comment: He's working with some legacy code. Some programmer decided to do it this way.

Comment: Well, yes. But _why_? Why would someone do that? Is there anything to be gained by this technique, or is it purely a matter of something thinking they're being clever?

Comment: Can't think of any advantage doing it this way.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: It is a silly micro-optimization. Someone thought compare with zero would be faster in a tight loop than comparing two variables.

Answer (score 3):

The `blocks` variable is initialized ahead of `data` by `nblocks` (assuming `sizeof(uint32_t) == 4`). The `for` loop then starts from the beginning of `data` up to the end pointed to by `blocks`, so negative indices are used. So, it is not looping through the data backwards, but forwards.

Comment: I concur with it moving forwards.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's an algorithm used hashing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash), your source might be that one https://github.com/JeffBezanson/libsupport/blob/master/MurmurHash3.c ;)

Comment: I have a different source, but I believe this algorithm is quite standard. The wiki article implies it's going forwards (I saw it earlier), but you're confirming it is going backwards, with the remainder being at the beginning of the input, correct?

Comment: What the hell is the `#define` for?  Why didn't they just say `p[i]`?

Comment: Interesting that the 128 bit hash runs backwards, but the 32 bit one runs forwards.